# Adding option to Select Deliver date for WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to add calendar on the website where customer can select deliver date and upon completion of order delivery date is added in the database and showed on order single page. Here is the code I am using let me know what is wrong with what code.

to Display the calendar

```
<div id="calendarContainer"></div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Initialize datepicker
        $("#calendarContainer").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                $(".selected-date").text(dateText);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    data: {
                        action: "<?php echo is_user_logged_in() ? 'set_selected_date_session' : 'set_selected_date_session_guest'; ?>",
                        selectedDate: dateText
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log("Selected date sent to server:", dateText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This is code in php

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

// Save selected date to session
add_action('wp_ajax_set_selected_date_session', 'set_selected_date_session');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_set_selected_date_session', 'set_selected_date_session_guest');

function set_selected_date_session() {
    if (isset($_POST['selectedDate'])) {
        $_SESSION['selectedDate'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['selectedDate']);
        wp_send_json_success();
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}

function set_selected_date_session_guest() {
    if (isset($_POST['selectedDate'])) {
        $_SESSION['selectedDate'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['selectedDate']);
        wp_send_json_success();
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}

// Save selected date to order meta upon completion
function save_selected_date_to_order($order_id) {
    $selected_date = isset($_SESSION['selectedDate']) ? sanitize_text_field($_SESSION['selectedDate']) : '';

    if (!empty($selected_date)) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_selected_delivery_date', $selected_date);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'save_selected_date_to_order');
```

This is the code to show date on website that customer is selected

```
<b><span class="selected-date"></span></b>
```